# Constructive geometry visualization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xna, directx

I need to visualize constructive geometry in 3d using C#. And for that I want choose a library. Ideally, that library should be able to provide the following:

1. Rendering arbitrary polygons in 3d. Wireframe representation.
2. Orhtographic projection
3. Camera control. I need to be able to zoom-in/out, set center of rotation to turn camera around it.
4. Pick my polygons, edges, vertices with a mouse.
5. Draw text on top of vertices, edges and polygons.

Efficency isn't the priority, so it can be resonably slow if it can do these things right out of the box or provide a good high level service for it.

I tried to look at XNA. But as far as I understood it doesn't support visualization of polygons directly.

Comment: Managed Direct3d is pretty easy to pick up, and the features you describe are simple enough that I'm not sure a library on top of Direct3d would do you much good.  Are you restricted to using C#?  VTK is a nice visualization platform that could save you a bit of hassle.

Answer (score 2):

XNA **does** support visualization of polygons directly by providing access to the underlying Direct3D 9 GraphicsDevice object. You can also dynamically create a mesh and draw it in a managed way, however that will be slower.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawprimitives.aspx
and related methods.

Comment: I would rather prefer customizable viewer. I'm ready to cut some features for a speed of development. But thanks +1.

Answer (score 1):

There's several DirectX wrappers in c#. I would avoid Managed DirectX since it's deprecated, and you have only access to direct3d9.

The two most common libraries for DirectX are:

- [SlimDX](http://www.slimdx.org/)
- [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/)

Both work pretty well, and support latest DirectX feature set (SlimDX up to 11, SharpDX supports windows 8 and 11.1).

They both support what you need to do, it of course implies a bit of coding on your side.

Comment: I would rather prefer customizable viewer. I'm ready to cut some features for a speed of development.